# Attach and Configure JACOCO agent on Weblogic Server

Tags: weblogic, jacoco

My Application is deployed on weblogic server. I want to attach jacoco agent to the weblogic server.

Is there any way to attach it in weblogic server using startWeblogic or setDomainEnv.
OR
is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/java-ee-6-example-galleria-part-2.html ? It talks about adding Jacoco as a JVM arg, which you should be able to set in your start or setDomain scripts

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But here the configuration is done only for glassfish server. If I try to find out the same thing in weblogic server. The corresponding config.xml file does not contain <server-config java-config> tag.                                    Is there any other way for weblogic server?

Comment: There are multiple places you can put it. For instance, add it to `EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES` inside setDomainEnv. This person did it on a java options line with tomcat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856744/getting-code-coverage-of-my-application-using-jacoco-java-agent-on-tomcat

Comment: I have tried it. But I was not able to find any "Jacoco.exec" file in destination folder that I have given in destfile tag in JAVA_OPTIONS in startweblogic.cmd. I think startweblogic is not taking that JAVA_OPTION.                                                         Will u plz help me out in this. This is taking a lot of concern for me. I really appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this with Weblogic 12.1.3 on Linux and it worked.

```
setenv JAVA_OPTIONS -javaagent:$JACOCO_HOME/lib/jacocoagent.jar\=includes\=ccdemo.\*,output\=tcpserver,address\=\*
```

There were no changes to `startWeblogic.sh` or other files needed.